# SUM of multi (relate to another table) rows record in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ms-access

I have two tables an tblOrder and tblOrderDetail Table.

tblOrderDetail contain below rows:

```
OrderDetailID  OrderID  Product  Quantity  UnitPrice  Discount   Total

    1            1        ABC      10      $240.00      10     $2,160.00 
    2            2        CDF      100     $200.00      10     $18,000.00
    3            3        GHI      200     $150.00       0     $30,000.00
    4            1        XYZ      40      $100.00       5     $3,800.00
```

i want sql query to get Subtotal column in tblOrder, which are sum of relate OrderID Total from tblOrderDetail like this:

```
OrderID     Sub Total
  1         $5,960.00  
  2         $18,000.00
  3         $30,000.00
```

i try this sql query:

```
SELECT 
    OrderID
    ,(
        SELECT 
            SUM(((tblOrderDetail.UnitPrice) - (tblOrderDetail.UnitPrice * (tblOrderDetail.Discount / 100))) * (tblOrderDetail.Quantity)) 
        FROM 
            tblOrderDetail 
        WHERE tblOrderDetail.OrderID = tblOrder.OrderID
    ) AS [Sub Total] 
FROM 
    tblOrder
```

but it gives this

```
OrderID     Sub Total
  1         $0.00  
  2         $0.00
  3         $0.00
```

Note i want Sub Total column dynamically not by Sum of Total Column in tblOrderDetail Table.

I hope somebody can make sense of what I'm saying and hopefully help me achieve this!

Comment: why are you using equation to find total as you already have field in your column

Comment: Do you wanna add resultset into tblOrder after calculating total ?

Comment: As i mention i have two tables tblOrder and tblOrderDetail i want to add resultset (SubTotal) into tblOrder after calculating values from tblOrderDetail as mention my query but its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Group by Clause to with SUM aggregate function,

```
    Select *, sum(Total) as totalforOrder from ordertbl group by OrderID;
```

Demo [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb22e8/7)

as per your question, here is a correlated query

```
  SELECT 
tblOrder.OrderID
,(
    SELECT 
        SUM(((tblOrderDetail.UnitPrice) - (tblOrderDetail.UnitPrice * (tblOrderDetail.Discount / 100))) * (tblOrderDetail.Quantity)) 
    FROM 
        tblOrderDetail 
    WHERE tblOrderDetail.OrderID = tblOrder.OrderID
) AS SubTotal
```

FROM 
    tblOrder;

Its working fine on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e7d6/6)

[image]

Comment: if you wanna calculate total using equation then have a look this Demo : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb22e8/10

Comment: as i mention i have two tables tblOrder and tblOrderDetail
i want to add resultset (SubTotal) into tblOrder after calculating values from tblOrderDetail as mention my query but its not working.

Comment: @FC3D I have added correlated query for you, its working fine but i must say use inner join or group by clause to get result set much faster and efficient

Comment: thanks its working i had another problem in my query that's why its not working
Actually i have big table with lot of fields that's why its not working anyway thanks for you assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use Group by to do this

```
Select OrderID, sum(Total) as [Sub Total] from tblOrderDetail group by OrderID;
```

[You can get more details here !](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FKSSOpQe5Jc)